# is there have a concurrent List in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I add some elements in HashMap in flutter like this:

```
void loadingMoreChannel(RefreshController _refreshController) async {
    articleRequest.pageNum = articleRequest.pageNum + 1;
    List<Channel> channels = await Repo.getChannels(articleRequest);
    channels.addAll(channels);
    _refreshController.loadComplete();
  }
```

first step fetched some channel information from the server side, then add the channel info into List, shows error:

```
Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:15) of '_GrowableList'.<…>
```

what should I do to add the channel elements into list concurrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to rename the variable. You can just do

```dart
void loadingMoreChannel(RefreshController _refreshController) async {
    articleRequest.pageNum = articleRequest.pageNum + 1;
    List<Channel> result = await Repo.getChannels(articleRequest);
    channels.addAll(result); //it was having same name
    _refreshController.loadComplete();
  }
```